# List.IndexOf returns 1 c#

Tags: .net

`IndexOf` is returning 1 for the last element of the list. Why?

**This code is not used by me . I am just giving you guys an idea about my asked context through the code mentioned below**
E.g. List:

```
 List<int> abc = new List<int>();
 abc.Add(1);
 abc.Add(2);
 abc.Add(41);
// i.e index 0 hold 1 index 1 hold 2 and index 3 hold 41
//abc[0] = 1;
//abc[1] = 2;
//abc[3] = 41;
```

then checking index like:

```
foreach (int i in abc)
{
    //for first two index[0,1] IndexOf() works fine but when foreach loop hole i=41       then IndexOf() returns 1 i.e is index=1 why??
    int index = abc.IndexOf(i);
}
```

Comment: Your example code would cause a compile time error. The `abc` list has not items in it, so accessing by index would cause exceptions.

Comment: You get an argumentoutofrangeexception on abc[0] = 1;

Comment: As Oded says. If you are going to include code working code is always good. Or at least some pseudo code to indicate what is happening (eg a line saying "add 100 values to list from database" or something. If your given code isn't valid and doesn't contain your error then its much harder to find the problem...

Comment: @Kannas: That is fair enough. But you can try to duplicate the error in working code. Or at least check that the code you gives is valid and produces the error. In this case the code actually caused me more confusion than anything as I tried to get it to run and compile and then work out if you really meant a List or if you meant a fixed length Array since that first block will not run at all...

Comment: Chris i am not getting any error . It just that i am using something in a wrong way. newayz i'll take care of what you said.

Comment: @Kannas: I see now (from your accepted answer) where your problem was. You might want to think about mentioning the wider context sometimes when asking questions. Not necessarily in great detail but to make it clear that your problem was with accessing the list elements in the foreach loop rather than specifically with the indexOf. I think recognising when your problem is with your methodology is one of those things that comes with experience though...

Comment: Sure Chris i got your point...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[List.IndexOf()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4w08k17.aspx) method returns first occurrence of element (item) within the list if an element is found. If your list contains duplicate element then you may continue your search into the list using [List.IndexOf(item,index)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx).

```
    var abc = new List<int>();
    abc.Add(1);
    abc.Add(2);
    abc.Add(41);
    abc.Add(2);
    int index=-1;
    foreach (int i in abc)
    {
        index = abc.IndexOf(i,index+1);
        Console.WriteLine(index);
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Is this actually the code you are using? The [docs for `List.Indexof`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bd0tetb.aspx) says "Returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence of a value in the `List<T>`" which means if your list contained 1,2,3,2 then your index for the last one would be 3.

The following code snippet (runnable in Linqpad) demonstrates...

```
var abc =new List<int>();
abc.Add(1);
abc.Add(3);
abc.Add(42);
abc.Add(45);
abc.Add(3);

foreach(int i in abc)
{
    int index=abc.IndexOf(i).Dump();
}
```

output is:

```
0
1
2
3
1
```

Note: `Dump()` is a useful LinqPad extension method used to print an object. Remove and replace if you want to run this code in some other context.

Comment: Then check if the last element is the same as that at index one in your list. I suspect it probably will be... (or your list only has two elements ;-) ).

Comment: Two downvotes with no comment? I really would like to know what is wrong with this answer so I can both correct it and learn from wherever I have gone wrong...

Answer (score 1):

`IndexOf` returns the first index where the match is found. It's quite possible that your last element value is already present at the index 1. Double check all values in your list.

If problem persisted then you can post the code to re-produce the problem. The current code that you have posted won't work as is - for example, line such as `abc[3] = 41` from your code will not work unless you have added at least 4 elements into your list.

Answer (score 1):

Your code would not work. This example will and gives the expected answer.

```
var abc = new List<int>(4);  
abc.Add(1);  
abc.Add(2);  
abc.Add(3);  
abc.Add(41);  

abc[0] = 1;
abc[1] = 2;
abc[3] = 41;


foreach (int i in abc)
{
   int index = abc.IndexOf(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

kannas use for loop instead of foreach. Doing this i'll avoid IndexOf() method

```
for(int i =0;i<abc.Count;i++)//use index i
```

Comment: I'm guessing that he was being given down votes for code that didn't compile or once you had edited it to compile demonstrate the problem. And if this was the accepted answer then the question apparently wasn't about IndexOf at all but about being unable to reference the correct element in a for each loop. The question was quite explicitly "IndexOf is returning 1 for the last element of the list. Why?" and in no world should an answer to that be "Don't use that". It apparently solves his problem but not a problem that was in the question.

Comment: @Chris Search over stackOverflows asked questions where people explain their question by giving examples to make things easier for us and their examples were not found in correct format/syntex.

Comment: Before editing the code kannas assume you guys smart enough.And now i think Kannas edited his code for better presentation.

Comment: its not just the code compiling though, its the fact that the error does not occur in his code even after it has been fixed up. You are right that he has edited his code now but I wouldn't say it was for better presentation but adding in necessary information (ie that those are not actually numbers that cause the bug). The error is clearly in code that is not in the question and I was intelligent enough to work out what the problem was. I should note that I am not one of the downvoters because I think the question was answerable by guesswork.

Comment: Chris I appreciate your effort.. :)